# Grep to multiple output files

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have one huge file (over 6GB) and about 1000 patterns. I want extract lines matching each of the pattern to separate file. For example my patterns are:

```
1
2
```

my file:

```
a|1
b|2
c|3
d|123
```

As a output I would like to have 2 files:

1:

```
a|1
d|123
```

2:

```
b|2
d|123
```

I can do it by greping file multiple times, but it is inefficient for 1000 patterns and huge file. I also tried something like this:

```
grep -f pattern_file huge_file
```

but it will make only 1 output file. I can't sort my huge file  - it takes to much time. Maybe AWK will make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F\| 'NR == FNR {
  patt[$0]; next
  }
{
  for (p in patt)
    if ($2 ~ p) print > p
  }' patterns huge_file
```

With some awk implementations you may hit the max number of open files limit.
Let me know if that's the case so I can post an alternative solution.

P.S.: This version will keep only one file open at a time:

```
awk -F\| 'NR == FNR {
  patt[$0]; next
  }
{
  for (p in patt) {
    if ($2 ~ p) print >> p
    close(p)
    }
  }' patterns huge_file
```

Comment: Thank you. I made script based on your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this (if I understand the problem) using bash "process substitution", e.g., consider the following sample data:

```
$ cal -h
   September 2013     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30
```

Then selective lines can be `grep`d to different output files in a single command as:

```
$ cal -h \
    | tee >( egrep '1'    > f1.txt ) \
    | tee >( egrep '2'    > f2.txt ) \
    | tee >( egrep 'Sept' > f3.txt )
```

In this case, each `grep` is processing the entire data stream (which may or may not be what you want: this may not save a lot of time vs. just running concurrent `grep` processes):

```
$ more  f?.txt
::::::::::::::
f1.txt
::::::::::::::
   September 2013     
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
::::::::::::::
f2.txt
::::::::::::::
   September 2013     
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30                 
::::::::::::::
f3.txt
::::::::::::::
   September 2013
```

Comment: if 1000 patterns it will run 1000 grep processes. Wrong for this case

Comment: It's just an example of a simple bash syntax that may be unfamiliar. (The "lots of processes == bad" is by no means axiomatic -- eg, consider "big data" processing architectures.) But you're right -- for 1000 patterns, it's simply impractical. (You'd need a script to generate the script...) Lots of proc's is only advantageous when the work is being broken down into pieces -- and here, it's not. That's the real caveat/problem. Also...is this a one-time thing (with no time/space requirements)? Or is it part of a business workflow? If the latter, map/reduce + hadoop may be a the better option.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (although `sed` might not be the quickest tool!):

```
 sed 's,.*,/&/w &_file,' pattern_file > sed_file
```

Then run this file against the source:

```
 sed -nf sed_file huge_file
```

I did a cursory test and the `GNU sed version 4.1.5` I was using, easily opened 1000 files OK, however your unix system may well have smaller limits.

Answer (score 0):

Grep cannot output matches of different patterns to different files. Tee is able to redirect it's input into multiple destinations, but i don't think this is what you want.

Either use multiple grep commands or write a program to do it in Python or whatever else language you fancy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this need, so I added the capability to my own copy of grep.c that I happened to have lying around.  But it just occurred to me: if the primary goal is to avoid multiple passes over a huge input, you could run egrep once on the huge input to search for any of your patterns (which, I know, is not what you want), and redirect its output to an intermediate file, then make multiple passes over that intermediate file, once per individual pattern, redirecting to a different final output file each time.